# How to recreate Instagram swipable pictures in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to make a Widget which holds pictures and is swipable. When I swipe, I want to see the next picture, and if I swipe far enough it switches to the next picture. If you've ever used Instagram, [this is](https://help.instagram.com/269314186824048) the feature I'm talking about.

Comment: you can use pageview

Comment: I didn't even know that existed, thank you very much!